How to ping Docker container from host and vice versa? Which network would be best to use?
I am new to networking but my target is to be able to ping a Docker container from the host and vice versa.
I know there are different types of networking in Docker (bridge,host,macvlan, [two types of ipvlan],none, overlay), however, I am not sure of the best approach for my situation. I think I wouldn't need the host, bridge and none. Am I right?
My ifconfig for the host is the following:
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:9e:c2:de:e3  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.110  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        ether 00:15:5d:02:15:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5199747  bytes 1163346264 (1.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 7198  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 123732  bytes 272159622 (272.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 46761  bytes 11941315 (11.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 46761  bytes 11941315 (11.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

in addition, I would like to start my IP address after 110. Is that even possible and can I expose ports as well?
Edit 1:
docker network create -d macvlan     --subnet=192.168.3.0/24     --ip-range=192.168.3.0/24     -o parent=eth0 macvlan_net

Would I need to also need to add the macvlan on the host as well?
I have done this in host:
sudo ip link add macvlan-net link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge
sudo ip addr add 192.168.3.150/24 dev macvlan-net
sudo ip link set macvlan-net up

Which got,
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:24:67:e6:93  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.110  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        ether 00:15:5d:02:15:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2791249  bytes 616025561 (616.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3916  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 95672  bytes 99285451 (99.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 17230  bytes 5598854 (5.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17230  bytes 5598854 (5.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

macvlan-net: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.150  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::48a4:e4ff:fe53:ff35  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4a:a4:e4:53:ff:35  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 753176  bytes 168846742 (168.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1074  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 54  bytes 5441 (5.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

but still I was not able ping the container from host and vice versa. I am basically trying to use the .3.XXX onward for creating the connection with the container

Macvlan is the most complex to set up. The idea is to assign an IP address for the docker from the same subnet as your host. For example, your host has the IP address 192.168.3.110, Assuming it is a static address, you can assign another static IP address say 192.168.3.111 to the docker container using macvlan. This should not need any changes to the host's ip configuration. Can you add the docker-compose.yml file where you set up the container and the docker network? Anyways, how does this question relate to Ubuntu?

@user68186 Thank you for your reply. I am just running the latest build images like docker run -d --name my_container --network macvlan_net --ip 192.168.3.120 alpine sleep 3600, Is there a (Detailed) Tutorial on proper setup and which approach would be best for my case? I am also new in Docker, so when you run the build using the DockerFile will it also use docker-compose.yml to build the image? Sorry, I am using Ubuntu as my OS and I was browsing for answers to my question for docker and saw a post on this site, therefore, I created this question. If this is the wrong place apologies.

I don't have any experience with Docker's macvlan network. You may get better responses in forums and sites related to Docker and related to network management. For this reason I am going to flag this question to be unrelated to Ubuntu.


I think I wouldn't need the host, bridge and none. Am I right?

No, not right. These are exactly the network drivers you normally want to use.
Please read the very well-written Docker documentation on networking.
It describes in clear and simple terms how Docker networks function, and the difference between them.
To quote the relevant section:

Drivers
The following network drivers are available by default, and provide
core networking functionality:



Driver
Description




bridge
The default network driver.


host
Remove network isolation between the container and the Docker host.


none
Completely isolate a > container from the host and other containers.


overlay
Overlay networks connect multiple Docker daemons together.


ipvlan
IPvlan networks provide full control over both IPv4 and IPv6 addressing.


macvlan
Assign a MAC address to a container.




"Bridge" is the default mode, where each container gets an IP address on a dedicated subnet (the default subnet of 172.17.0.0/16 or a separate subnet for Docker Compose stacks). In this mode, Docker performs NAT (network address translation) between the host and the containers.
"Host" is the mode where containers get an IP address directly on the host subnet.
"None" disables network for the container.
In both "Bridge" and "Host" mode, you can ping the containers, and containers can ping the host (provided that ping is installed in the container).
For "Bridge" mode the container would have an 172.17.0.X address, and for "Host" mode the container would be assigned a DHCP or static IP address on the host subnet (e.g. 192.168.1.X for most home networks).
For more advanced usecases, you might have to look into "IPvlan" or "MACvlan", which give you full control over addresses, or by emulating a MAC address, so the host network can handle the device accordingly.
See the Network drivers documentation for more details.

Thank you for the reply, Well, I have a project that host communicates with hardware (Microcontrollers like Raspberry Pi, beaglebones, etc) and it uses IP addresses with ports (TCP and udp) to be able to transmit messages. I was thinking of using the Docker container as if these hardware were containers and thought of using 192.168. but set them on one separate network but have a route for the container to communicate with the host (192.168.3.110).

If you have another question, please post another question. I've answered your question as it is written. Please see The Tour about this site - this isn't like a normal discussion forum to exchange ideas.

Sorry it is not the other question, it is related to this one. I just wanted to give the full picture to understand why I asked this question.

For more advanced usecases, you might look into the IPvlan or MACvlan networks. I expanded my answer a bit.

I have looked into the MACvlan and IPvlan, I feel that I have made a mistake somewhere. See the edited part in the question.

I haven't used any of those myself, so unfortunately can't help you, sorry..

No problem, I appreciate your help. Do you know if there are any detailed tutorials about Networking for docker and recommend reading? (I would prefer any recent blogs/website/etc.)
